# Best way to validate a component passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-proptypes

What is the best way to validate proptypes that are going to be stateless components , other than `Proptypes.func` ?

Let's say I have a `NestedDashboardItem` component that is going to receive an `Icon` component as a prop . I don't want to pass it as a child and use it from `props.children` because I have use cases where that'll be overkill like passing an array of child nested Links and such .

consider :

```
 <DashboardItem
     to="/route"
     icon={someIconComponent}
     text="sometext"
   />
```

and in the `DashboardItem` definition I want to validate this icon prop

```
   const DashboardItem = ({ text, icon, to, classes }) => {
      const Icon = icon;
      return (
        <ListItem
          button
          component={Link}
          to={to}
          activeClassName="active"
          className={classes.root}
        >
          <ListItemIcon className={cx(classes.dashboardIcon_wrapper)}>
            <Icon className={cx(classes.icon)} />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={text} />
        </ListItem>
      );
    };
```

I used `PropTypes.element` and it complained , so now what I'm asking is what is the best way to validate the `icon` prop , other than `PropTypes.func` ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate in the `icon` property?

Comment: "I used PropTypes.element and it complained" What did it say?

Comment: @juliobetta I want to validate the incoming icon component itself , usually it's a stateless one , which is just a function really . reason being I might pass it other kind of components and am searching for something other than just validating for a function

Comment: @Aaronius it said prop not valid , function passed but it expected an element .

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way. Use `PropTypes.func`.

Comment: I sometimes won't be passing a stateless component , I need something generic